# how to reduce spacing between multiple table views?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

In this I had placed two table views on a single scroll view so that i had given constraints where as coming to landscape mode the space between the first table view and the other table view is increasing and is as shown here :

[image: here]

In portrait it works fine and there is not that much space can anyone help me how to reduce this ?

Comment: `tableview` itself has `scrollview` and why are you using two `tableviews`. I am sure it can be done through one `tableview`

Comment: no as per my requirement i had placed a scroll view and on it i placed a two table views on one table view i am having button if its active then it need to show remaining data if not it should hide

Comment: no image was fine i was showing the space @byJeevan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad idea using two table Views in scrollView. Use one tableView and make manipulate with items in dataSource which fill tableView, after items changed reload needed cells, and table view redraw.

Comment: but i am getting data from two web services so one data will be displayed first time after loading screen and i am having radio button on the first table view if it is active then the other table view needs to display the remaining data which i got from another web services